# Why is the Erdos-Renyi model called a mean field theory of percolation?

Tags: random-graphs, percolation

ER can be viewed as edge percolation on a complete graph. But some sources say that physicists like to refer to it as a 'mean field theory' of percolation. Why is that so? Does it correspond to some special case of the partition function for percolation?

Thanks, this is just something I see papers say all the time (ER is mean field percolation), but I have not found a single reference indicating what exactly that means and why that's so.